# Как создать таблицу из JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, api

Получаю данные с [этой страницы](https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates?periodicity=0). Я понял как положить каждый объект в отдельный tr тег:

```
` const nbrbURI = 'https://www.nbrb.by/API/';

function ratestoday() {
    $.getJSON(nbrbURI + 'exrates/rates?periodicity=0')
        .done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                $('<tr>', { text: JSON.stringify(item.Cur_OfficialRate) }).appendTo($('.exRates'));
            });
        });
    };

ratestoday()
`
```

А вот как сделать таблицу, чтобы всё совпадало - не понимаю. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table class="exRates">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Cur_id</td>
      <td>Cur_OfficialRate</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
const nbrbURI = 'https://www.nbrb.by/API/';
let tbody = $('.exRates').find('tbody');

function ratestoday() {
  $.getJSON(nbrbURI + 'exrates/rates?periodicity=0')
  .done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
      tbody.append( `<tr><td>${item.Cur_id}</td><td>${item.Cur_OfficialRate}</td></tr>` );
    });
  });
};

ratestoday()
```

`data` должна содержать что-то подобное:

```
[
  {
    "Cur_ID": 190,
    "Date": 1.234
  },
  {
    "Cur_ID": 290,
    "Date": 2.356
  },
  {
    "Cur_ID": 291,
    "Cur_OfficialRate": 1.8684
  }
]
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я уже понял алгоритм вставки. Он такой же как у вас, но сам код я сделал чуть иначе - через fetch.

Comment: Только у меня теперь вопрос: как мне редактировать порядок? Мне нужно популярные валюты поднять вверх. Я понял, что алгоритм такой:
1. Получаем из массива нужные валюты - добавляем в таблицу
2. Удаляем из массива выбранные элементы
3. Дальше делаем, как было. Верно?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через fetch:

```
fetch('https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates?periodicity=0')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
    $(res).each((index, item)=>{
        $('.exRates').append(`<tr><td>${item.Cur_Scale}</td><th scope="row">${item.Cur_Name}</th><td>${item.Cur_OfficialRate}</td><td>${item.Cur_Abbreviation}</td></tr>`)
    })
})
```